# How to specify env.shell while in fabric.operations.execute

Tags: python, fabric

I am using fabric.tasks.execute to execute commands on remote servers, and need to use different shell depending on system. now my code is like:

```
def run_test(server_ip, server_shell):
    execute(test,server_ip,server_shell,host=server_ip) # host can be specified in execute argument

def test(ip,shell):
    env.shell=shell
    run('command')
```

I can live with this but prefer execute specifing env.shell the command will use instead of assigning it within the task, that's just simple and clean. Can i use something like:

```
def run_test(server_ip, server_shell):
    execute(test,server_ip,server_shell,host=server_ip,*shell=server_shell*) # host can be specified in execute argument

def test(ip,shell):
    run('command')
```

Answer (score 1):

[`execute()` docs](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/api/core/tasks.html#fabric.tasks.execute) say that only `host`, `hosts`, `role`, `roles` and `exclude_hosts` keyword parameters are special; the rest is passed to the task as is i.e., `shell` is passed to `test()`:

```
def test(shell):
    with settings(shell=shell):
        run('command')

execute(test, shell=server_shell, host=server_ip)
```